# Problems with Textfields and Animation Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, animation, button

so I got 8 Textfields and a plus button (clickable ImageView). When I press the plus "button" the next textfield appears and the button moves down.

`UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            self.imageV.center.y += 60
        }, completion: nil)`

This works great but when I write into the textfield the button moves back to the first position.

Comment: Add you UI images.

Comment: Have you given your "plus button" constraints? If so, you cannot simply change the frame (as in setting `.center.y` value)... auto-layout will re-enforce the constraints on the next UI update.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But have you an idea how to fix that?

Comment: @JulsGra - you need to provide more information. Is your "plus button" added in Storyboard or via code? Have you given it constraints? If so, what constraints? *"... the next textfield appears ..."* Appears how? Adding a new text field to the view, or showing one that is hidden? How are the text fields positioned... with `.frame =` or with constraints?